# Inconsistent relationships with self referencing breeze entities

Tags: javascript, breeze, single-page-application

I am using breeze (version: "1.4.2", metadataVersion: "1.0.5") and have defined a self referencing entity type called **Role**. The application queries a web service for a list of roles which returns an array of items in a flat structure. These items are then used to create the role entities. I have defined two navigational properties **Parent** and **Child** that are used to build a tree structure from these elements.

Breeze is able to parse these items and setup the relationships. However, there are instances where if a parent has not been defined before a child element, the relationship is not created. If I have a look at the entities that have been created, all the entities are there and they have all the correct properties and values have been set.

*Note: If I order the items so that parent items are always created first, everything works fine. However I don't believe I need to be doing this.*

Is there something I am missing which causes the relationships to not be established correctly every time with a random list ordering?

Breeze Config

```
var dataService = new breeze.DataService(
  { 
     serviceName: ... + '/breeze',
     hasServerMetadata: false
  });

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ 
    dataService: dataService
});

var metadataStore = manager.metadataStore;
manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);
```

My role definition:

```
store.addEntityType({
    shortName: 'Role',
    namespace: '68e46ee6-e08c-4877-a1fc-62458244834d',
    autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.KeyGenerator,
    dataProperties: {
        'ID': { dataType: breeze.DataType.Guid, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
        'Name': { dataType: breeze.DataType.String, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: false },
        'ParentRoleID': { dataType: breeze.DataType.String, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: false },
    },
    navigationProperties: {
        'Parent': {
            entityTypeName: 'Role:#68e46ee6-e08c-4877-a1fc-62458244834d',
            foreignKeyNames: ['ParentRoleID'],
            isScalar:  true                 
        },  
        'Children': {
            entityTypeName: 'Role:#68e46ee6-e08c-4877-a1fc-62458244834d',
            isScalar:  false                
        },  
    }
});
```

Let me know if I need to provide any further information.

Comment: How would you expect Breeze to create a navigation property to an entity that does not yet exist?

Comment: At the moment it appears to be working. If I provide the same data repeatedly it creates the links and works correctly, however there are random instance in which it doesnt.